# Converting delimted names to a vector of strings in R

Tags: r, string

I have a list of names like below

`100m     LJ      SP     HJ   400m`

I would like to have this in the following format:

`"100m", "LJ", "SP", "HJ", "400m"`

Is there any function that preexisted in R?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `gsub()` here, twice:

```r
x <- "100m     LJ      SP     HJ   400m"
output <- gsub("\\s+", ", ", gsub("(\\S+)", "\"\\1\"", x))
output

[1] "\"100m\", \"LJ\", \"SP\", \"HJ\", \"400m\""
```

Comment: I need commas in between. How can I get those?

Comment: Do you want a string with actual terms in double quotes?  Please include the exact output you want.

Comment: The required output should have all the strings in quotes with comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dQuote`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(str1, '\\w+', function(x) dQuote(x, FALSE))
#[1] "\"100m\"     \"LJ\"      \"SP\"     \"HJ\"   \"400m\""
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
paste(dQuote(strsplit(str1, "\\s+")[[1]], FALSE), collapse = " ")
[1] "\"100m\" \"LJ\" \"SP\" \"HJ\" \"400m\""
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "100m     LJ      SP     HJ   400m"
```

Comment: I would like to use output as ```names(df) <- str1```.  That's why I need commas in between. ```"100m", "LJ", "SP", "HJ", "400m"```

Comment: @RamakrishnaS then you don't need the `paste` `collapse`

Comment: So what is the final code I can use. Please let me know

Comment: @RamakrishnaS I meant `dQuote(strsplit(str1, "\\s+")[[1]], FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- "100m     LJ      SP     HJ   400m"
x_split = stringr::str_split(x, '\\s+')
cat(paste0('"', paste(x_split, collapse="\", \""), '"'))
```

This is the closest I got.

Output:

`"c("100m", "LJ", "SP", "HJ", "400m")"`